# What is the appropriate type of caulking around a kitchen sink?

Tags: repair, caulking

The caulking around my sink has worn/rotted away and I've removed it properly, but I've been looking into what I kind of caulking to use, and there seem to be many different types, so I'm a bit unsure of what to do.

Which type of caulking is used for a kitchen sink (the gap between the kitchen sink and the counter-top? Does anything else need to be applied in addition to the caulking?

Comment: It's best to ask multiple questions, if you have multiple questions. Sticking a bunch of questions together into a single post, makes it difficult to answer your questions. Please consider splitting #2 & 3 into separate questions.  #1 is far too broad to be answered, and should be edited to be more focused. "What type of caulk should be used around my sink?", for example.

Comment: @Tester101 I split up the questions, hopefully it won't appear as if I'm spamming the forums.

Comment: For the actual sink?  Like in between the sink and the counter area?

Comment: @DMoore the gap between the sink and the counter.

Comment: @MarkE We don't mind lots of questions, feel free to ask as many as you like.  Hope you get the information you're looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a 100% silicone clear caulk and since it is near a sink I would get something that is mold resistant.

Silicone for the sink to counter binding and its flexibility with temperature change.

Clear because you don't want to have staining issues down the road.  Also if you need to add caulk down the road - clear matches clear.

[GE Silicone II](http://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-2-8-oz-Silicone-II-Kitchen-and-Bath-Clear-Caulk-GE284-3TG/100004845#.UYNKdMojs-A)

I have used this on almost anything.

Comment: Why does it *need* to be clear?

Comment: Clear - because it is less likely to have color damage due to staining.  Yes you can white caulk a white sink and it will look good when you do it.  But that white caulk can get some grease or coffee on it and all of a sudden you have beige caulk around your sink.  Looking at the best long-term solution.

Comment: OK I guess you could go black caulk on a black sink - unless people have had staining/color changes with the black caulk.

Comment: Those are good points, you should include them in your answer.

Answer (score 4):

For the joint between the counter top and the tiles, you can use any flexible, preferably mold resistant, caulking from your local hardware store.

You should also be able to find it in a color that matches your grout.

For the joint between the sink and the bench, I use a clear, waterproof, flexible one.

Answer (score 0):

As a plumber have always used a bead of plumbers putty that u have rolled in your hands to soften and warm. Not messy and last for life of sink.